# How to fix Python requests.post CSV error

Tags: python-3.x, csv, response

I have this code running, creating CSV and trying to upload. Once I manually open created file, and copy paste content via Postman, all works.

Could you please advice what is the problem over here?

I tried to build CSV and post it to API using Pythons CSV and Requests libraries.

But once I come to `request.post` part API sends me reply 400

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc
import requests
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import time

url =        '&csvCodePage=65001&csvColumnDelimiter=%2C&csvTextQualifier=%22&SourceActionTemplate=MassClientAdd'    \
  '&editActionTemplate=MassClientEdit'
filename = 'C:\\storeapi\\data.csv'
headers = {
'Authorization': 'secretKey=""',
'Accept': 'text/csv',
'Content-Type': 'text/csv;charset=UTF-8'
}
now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
connection_string = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=XXX;DATABASE=XXX;UID=XXXXX;PWD=XXXXX;'
connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(
"SELECT TOP(1) P.clients_email_address AS Email, "
"CASE WHEN p.clients_phone like '' THEN '' "
"ELSE CONCAT('1', REPLACE(p.clients_phone, ' ', '')) "
"END AS mobilePhone, "
"P.last_name AS LastName, "
"P.first_name AS FirstName, "
"P.middle_name AS MiddleName, "
"CAST(CASE WHEN p.sex = '1' THEN 'Male' "
"ELSE 'Female' END As varchar) AS Sex, "
"format(P.birthday, 'dd.MM.yyyy') AS BirthDate, "
"IsSubscribedByEmail = 'TRUE', "
"IsSubscribedBySms = 'TRUE', "
"H.name AS CustomFieldClientsStore, "
"SourceDateTimeUtc = '' "
"FROM tor.CLIENT P "
"INNER JOIN tor.Store H ON P.store_id = H.id "
"INNER JOIN tor.Request R ON P.id = R.client_id "
"WHERE H.name LIKE '%KIDS%' AND P.last_name <> 'АКТ' AND p.clients_email_address like '%@%'"
"AND (CAST(r.registration_date AS DATE) between DATEADD(day, -14, convert(date, GETDATE())) "
"AND DATEADD(day, 0, convert(date, GETDATE())));")
#
rows = cursor.fetchall()
datacol = [row for row in rows]

def create_csv(datacol):
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, dialect='excel', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(
        ["Email", "mobilePhone", "LastName", "FirstName", "MiddleName", "Sex", "BirthDate",     "IsSubscribedByEmail",
         "IsSubscribedBySMS", "CustomFieldClientsStore", "SourceDateTimeUtc"])
    writer.writerows(datacol)


# time.sleep(500)
#create_csv(datacol)
#with open(filename, encoding='utf-8', ) as file:
#    content = file.read()
files = {'file': (filename, open(filename, 'rb'), 'text/csv')}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)
print(headers)
print(url)
print(response)
print(response.text)
connection.close()


<Response [400]>
{"status":"ProtocolError","errorMessage":" Unknown column exist in file --    ff7497df26c25afb4810c3ac8578680e. Make sure you define column name correctly, defined deliminator c  correctly, and you have correct file coding.}
```

Comment: Check the columns of your database. From the error it says your CSV file is defining a column that does not exist in the DB.

Comment: Gino, the thingy is if I open newly created file and run it trough postman, I get 200 ok response and data gets in. Does it neccessary means that all columns are persistent? From an eye comparison it looks decent to me. All determined columns are in file. Nothing extra... My thought is may be csv INDEX column 0 is failing a job?